# Can I remove and re-add a replicated folder (DFS) without it replicating the files all over again?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs

My question (should be) fairly easy to answer.

If I have server1 replicating data to server2, folder A.. and I remove the replicated folder in DFS management, then re-add this folder (perhaps in a new replication group) and link it to the same folder A.. Will it simply check for the existence of files and, if so, skip these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, basically what you'd be doing is what microsoft calls 'Pre-seeding' http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495044.aspx

It does a quick checksum and should keep files that are the same. However I've seen this go awry, in that case make sure your PreExisting and ConflictedAndDeleted folder sizes are set fairly large as DFS will move files it doesn't know how to deal with here. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754229.aspx

recovering those files is pretty easy, and microsoft even provided a tool - http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/10/15/restoredfsr-vbs-version-3-now-available.aspx

It's fairly safe especially with the cache it builds into the conflicted and deleted files.